# How to have multiple sitemaps for multiple domains hosted on one hosting account?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, sitemap

I have two domains pointing to the same hosting account. My code in the index.php page recognizes which domain and shows different content for each domain. However, both domains have the same `sitemap.xml` because there is only one sitemap in the `public_html` directory.

Is it possible to have two distinct sitemaps for the two domains?

Comment: Short answer: No. However, you can have two sitemaps with different file names...

Comment: @closetnoc, Thats ok, but how would google find it because I thought google only finds the sitemap.xml file

Comment: You can submit each sitemap using Google Search Console by creating both domains then submitting the sitemaps that way.

Comment: @closetnoc, do you mean submitting for example `www.domain1.com/sitemap1.xml` and `www.domain2.com/sitemap2.xml` and both `sitemap1.xml` and `sitemap2.xml` are in the same folder.

Comment: Yes. That should work. You can verify your sites in Google Search Console using a variety of ways including using a meta-tag. So that should work just fine!!

Comment: What about `robots.txt`? Can they both share the same file or is there a way to have two different `robots.txt` files for each?

Comment: They can use the same robots.txt just fine. However, if you are very clever, you can make a .txt file that is a script that returns different results. Personally, I would not work that hard.

Comment: @closetnoc, this is really helpful just one last clarification. The way I pointed the second domain to my hosting account is to use "Add Aliases domain" option on my godaddy account. My Code will show entirely different content for each  site and I am not going to link these sites to each other.  However, I am afraid that there will be some page ranking issues or penalties  by Google because the domains are hosted on the same hosting account - will this happen? Thanks

Comment: Not generally, however, if you do link the two, make it one link and not on every page otherwise Google will think you are up to something spammy. Do know that Google can figure just about everything and will relate your sites anyway with or without a link. Template, footer, header, or nav links can cause G to think you are trying to influence rank. So be natural and do what any reasonable webmaster would do.

Comment: Thanks, the two domains are for two completely different topics so I won't link them. The reason I hosted both on the same hosting account is to save money and time managing them. I am not trying to influence page rank. So, hosting the two domains on the same hosting account won't get me in trouble with Google?

Comment: Nope. Should not. Google does not care about that kinda stuff. They just want decent sites that people enjoy.

Comment: Anytime! We are here for you. There are some real exerts here so it is a good place to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

This way comes straight out of our .htaccess and works like a charm:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*myhost\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-com.xml [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*myhost\.ca$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap-ca.xml [NC]
```

Comment: I like your answer, however, I think the OP is using a single directory with PHP doing the work. If this is the case, your code example needs to change slightly to work properly. You are on the right track though!!

Comment: No, our setup is pretty much the same. The .htaccess is parsed for all requests, and if there's a request to either domain with /sitemap.xml as the requested file, the .htaccess code supplies one of the two sitemaps created in the sitemaps directory. He just has to replicate the directory structure - or use no directory and rewrite the redirect code.

Comment: I've updated to fit the original question, based on comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different sitemap files and add these seperate files to Google Webmaster Tools:

- `/sitemap1.xml`
- `/sitemap2.xml`

Another option is to use a rewriting mechanism to rewrite calls to the corresponding sitemap file. Using .htaccess or IIS-rewrite.

- `domain1.com/sitemap.xml` rewrites to `/sitemap1.xml`
- `domain2.com/sitemap.xml` rewrites to `/sitemap2.xml`

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear I will start from the WMT and work back to your server. Tl;DR Yes you can.

Each domain needs to have a separate WMT account for both it and for its www. version. Specify the preferred domain.

Put each domains sitemap in a separate, **DIFFERENT NAMED**, folder. Ensure you can publicly resolve that sitemap. Test the sitemap with WMT.

Browse to that folder and submit the `sitemap.xml` for each domain.

Verify in a day that it is crawling appropriately.

This does not depend on anything external to your current setup. You already have resolution sorted out.